# Python JavaScript Scraping: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape some info off of Yahoo Finance. Below is my simple code:

```
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL"
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/anaconda/bin/phantomjs")
browser.get(url)
browser.quit
```

But I get the following error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f4d26b367ef7> in <module>()
  8 webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/anaconda/bin/phantomjs")
  9 
---> 10 browser.get(url)

> /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-        py3.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in get(self, url)
266         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
267         """
--> 268         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
269 
270     @property

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py3.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
252 
253         params = self._wrap_value(params)
--> 254         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
255         if response:
256             self.error_handler.check_response(response)

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py3.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py in execute(self, command, params)
462         path = string.Template(command_info[1]).substitute(params)
463         url = '%s%s' % (self._url, path)
--> 464         return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
465 
466     def _request(self, method, url, body=None):

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py3.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py in _request(self, method, url, body)
485                 body = None
486             try:
--> 487                 self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
488                 resp = self._conn.getresponse()
489             except (httplib.HTTPException, socket.error):

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1237                 encode_chunked=False):
   1238         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1240 
   1241     def _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked):

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1283             # default charset of iso-8859-1.
   1284             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1285         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1286 
   1287     def getresponse(self):

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1232         else:
   1233             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1234         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1235 
   1236     def request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={}, *,

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1024         msg = b"\r\n".join(self._buffer)
   1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)
   1027 
   1028         if message_body is not None:

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in send(self, data)
962         if self.sock is None:
963             if self.auto_open:
--> 964                 self.connect()
965             else:
966                 raise NotConnected()

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in connect(self)
934         """Connect to the host and port specified in __init__."""
935         self.sock = self._create_connection(
--> 936             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
937         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
938 

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
720 
721     if err is not None:
--> 722         raise err
723     else:
724         raise error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
711             if source_address:
712                 sock.bind(source_address)
 713             sock.connect(sa)
714             return sock
715 

 ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I have checked other questions on this topic but couldn't find any relevant answers. How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The error stack trace gives us a hint that the actual issue may be in this line of the code:

```
webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/anaconda/bin/phantomjs")
```

As you are trying to open the URL through the instance `browser` as in `browser.get(url)`, the `browser` instance must be configured with the `absolute path` of the **`PhantomJS`** executable as follows (as on my Win8 machine through PyCharm IDE):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe")
browser.get(url)
# your code block
print(browser.title)
# your code block
browser.quit
```

The output on my console is as follows:

```
AAPL Key Statistics | Apple Inc. Stock - Yahoo Finance
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.